# How to compress TAR file in linux

Tags: linux

I have tried to tar.gz a folder but the output has created a big file. 
How can I compress it in linux?

e.g.

```
root]# tar cvzf Packages.tar.gz Packages/  
root]# ls -lrt

drwx------  2 root root     233472 Mar 14 16:49 Packages  
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3086809777 Mar 14 20:06 Packages.tar.gz
```

If you see above, the TAR file has become huge. How can I reduced its size?

Comment: Maybe the content of `Packages/` is "hugher"

Comment: It should already be compressed - what size is your packages folder?

Comment: Quite clearly, this is not a programming question.

Comment: @ErAB You could check that Packages.tar.gz is correct by running `file` on it, like `file Packages.tar.gz`.  The output will tell you if it's already packaged or not.

Comment: @Marwie: in above output it says size "233472" Packages and "3086809777" Packages.tar.gz.

Comment: @jim : file Packages.tar.gz 
Packages.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Mar 14 20:02:49 2014

Comment: Right click on folder Packages/ --> Properties --> 3,432 items, totalling 3.2 GB      and Right click on file Packages.tar.gz --> Properties --> 3.1 GB (3,086,809,777 bytes).

Comment: I have found a link which talks about the same condition in UNIX...but compress doesn't work in ubuntu/linux. http://sunsite.uakom.sk/sunworldonline/swol-03-1998/swol-03-unix101.html

Comment: Looks like it did some compression - keep in mind that compression only works well on content that is not compressed itself. Pictures and other media is usually already compressed very well.

Answer (score 2):

`233472` is not the full size of the directory. try `du -hsc *` to determine how big the two are.

`-z` to tar tells it to use gzip. You can get *usually* *slightly* better compression by using bzip2, ie. `tar cvjf Packages.tar.bz2 Packages/`

Answer (score 2):

The `-z` flag should have compressed the archive using gzip. The `--lzma` flag will give you a better compression ratio. If you are surprised at the size, then either you have more files in Packages/ than you originally expected, or they were already compressed. You typically get good compression rates on source code, but hopeless compression rates on videos and files that are already compressed.